# TinyURL JavaScript API triggers an error

Tags: javascript, tinyurl

I use the TinyURL API in one of my web applications. Until now, it worked fine but, today, an error occurs and I don't know why: I didn't modify my script since September!

Below is the code I use:

```
function getTinyURL(longURL, success)
{
    var API = 'http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/?url=',
        URL = API + encodeURIComponent(longURL) + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
        success && success(data);
    });                  
}

var url='http://[...]'; //A very long URL            
getTinyURL(url, function(data)
{
    if(data.tinyurl)
    {
        $('#link').text(data.tinyurl);
        $('#link').attr('href',encodeURI(data.tinyurl));
    }
    else
    {
        $('#link').text('An error occurs...');
        console.log('ERROR: '+data.error);
        $('#link').attr('href','#');
    }
});
```

As I already said, even if this code worked well before, today an error occurs. In the console log, this message is displayed: *The API call urlfetch.Fetch() required more quota than is available.*

I don't understand this message: does it mean that the error comes from TinyURL?
Should I change my code or should I wait for TinyURL does something against this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the TinyURL API, but to me that error sounds like they only allow you a certain number of calls (perhaps limited per month or something) and you've exceeded that quota. Could that be it?

Comment: Hm, it's quite possible... But if so, it's not very cool: do you know any way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Unless you can convince the "owner" of the app engine to pay something for it you will have to live with the limitations. You can read more about the quota limitations [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/kb/general.html#quota)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic behind the json-appspot service is not particularly sophisticated.

If you have ability to add logic to the server side, you can make and run something similar for yourself.  You'd need to install a "shim" or gateway script that connects to tinyurl.com, and returns a formatted JSON string.

Some examples:

- [PHP](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=php&file=tinyurl.php)
- [ASP classic](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=asp&file=tinyurl.asp)
- [ASPNET Handler](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=ashx&file=tinyurl.ashx)
- [Python](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=python&file=tinyurl.py)

They do the same thing. With either one you could just drop it on your server, then invoke it from within your pages like this, in jQuery:

```
var stub = "http://myserver.example.com/api/tinyurlshim.asp?url=",
    urlToEncode = "http://example.com/very/long/url/to/encode?with=query&params=too",
    url = stub + encodeURIComponent(urlToEncode);

$.getJSON(url, function(data) { alert('response: ' + data.tiny);} );
```